# Sanitize a unicode string for logging

Tags: c#, regex, unicode-string

I am writing a string sanitizer to use before I write data to a logfile with the following rules:

1. specified characters are whitelisted (`A-Za-z0-9` as well as `<>[],.:_-` and whitespace)
2. specified characters are converted to an english version of their name within triangle brackets (eg `"," => "<comma>"`, `"%" => "<percent>"`)
3. anything else is converted to its unicode number within triangle brackets (eg `"φ" => "<U+03C6>"`, `"π" => "<U+03C0>"`)

So far 1 and 2 are working, but not 3. Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static string Safe(string s)
    {
        s = s
            .Replace("<", "ooopen-angle-brackettt") // must come first
            .Replace(">", "ccclose-angle-brackettt") // must come first
            //.Replace(",", "<comma>") // allow
            //.Replace(".", "<dot>") // allow
            //.Replace(":", "<colon>") // allow
            .Replace(";", "<semi-colon>")
            .Replace("{", "<open-curly-bracket>")
            .Replace("}", "<close-curly-bracket>")
            //.Replace("[", "<open-square-bracket>") // allow
            //.Replace("]", "<close-square-bracket>") // allow
            .Replace("(", "<open-bracket>")
            .Replace(")", "<close-bracket>")
            .Replace("!", "<exclamation-mark>")
            .Replace("@", "<at>")
            .Replace("#", "<hash>")
            .Replace("$", "<dollar>")
            .Replace("%", "<percent>")
            .Replace("^", "<hat>")
            .Replace("&", "<and>")
            .Replace("*", "<asterisk>")
            //.Replace("-", "<dash>") // allow
            //.Replace("_", "<underscore>") // allow
            .Replace("+", "<plus>")
            .Replace("=", "<equals>")
            .Replace("\\", "<forward-slash>")
            .Replace("\"", "<double-quote>")
            .Replace("'", "<single-quote>")
            .Replace("/", "<forward-slash>")
            .Replace("?", "<question-mark>")
            .Replace("|", "<pipe>")
            .Replace("~", "<tilde>")
            .Replace("`", "<backtick>")
            .Replace("ooopen-angle-brackettt", "<open-angle-bracket>")
            .Replace("ccclose-angle-brackettt", "<close-angle-bracket>");
        // all working upto here. broken below:

        Regex itemRegex = new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9<>[\]:.,_\s-]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach (Match itemMatch in itemRegex.Matches(s))
        {
            // the reason for [0] and [1] is that I read that unicode consists of 2 characters
            s = s.Replace(
                itemMatch.ToString(),
                "<U+" +
                    (((int)(itemMatch.ToString()).ToCharArray()[0]).ToString("X4")).ToString() +
                    (((int)(itemMatch.ToString()).ToCharArray()[1]).ToString("X4")).ToString() +
                ">"
            );
        }
        return s;
    }
```

The regex part is not catching unicode characters in the input string. How can I fix this

Comment: You should escape `]`, `[^A-Za-z0-9<>[\]:.,_\s-]`, `{1}` is redundant, remove it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks i will update the question. note that this does not solve it tho.

Comment: You say "not catching unicode characters", could you provide a test case? I think you are dealing with emojis.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please use the φ and π as per part 3 in the question

Comment: Care to guess how your string looks like after the first two replaces? Suppose you started with `If 2 < 1, something strange is going on`.

Comment: What is the purpose of all this sanitation? What is unsafe about out-of-ASCII characters? Why not write UTF-8 log files?

Comment: Agreed, this all seems like a big fuss about nothing. Surely it would be better for the log to contain exactly the message which was originally generated, rather than a modified version. All these `<...>` tags are very verbose and will make it very difficult to read the logs clearly. And what on earth is the issue with exclamation marks, brackets etc? They're not even a UTF-related problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled good point. didn't think of that. i have updated the question

Comment: Try `return itemRegex.Replace(s, m =>
      string.Concat(m.Value.ToCharArray().Select(x => $"<U+{((int)x).ToString("X4")}>"))
     )` instead of the whole `foreach` block.

Comment: Your workaround for a "<>" problem will just make the bug less likely, but it's still there in different form. For instance, input string "ooopen-angle-brackettt" should not be changed at all.

Comment: Also, your assumption about "unicode consists of 2 characters" is invalid. Can't explain it in a comment, though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately that did not work. i get `φ => Ï†`

Comment: @mulllhausen See https://ideone.com/CtyUdC

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hmm that is weird. i am passing the data in from the browser, but even so, if i put a breakpoint in it still appears like a `φ` before doing the regex conversion

Comment: Then you must check the input data. This is something related to encoding, I guess.

Comment: This would be a lot slower with large string and a large number of computations. Consider using `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was assuming that a single unicode value existing in a C# `string` would convert to more than 1 item when that string was cast to a `char` array (`char[]`). If you mouse over the `string` and `char` types in visual studio then it actually tells you how these types are both related to unicode:

- `string`: represents text as a series of unicode characters
- `char`: represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit

What this means is each "letter" (ie. character) in a C# string is actually a unicode `char`, and so when you convert a string into a `char` array then each item of that array now contains 1 unicode character.

There is also one other missing piece of the puzzle: how do we know that `Regex.Match()` operates on 1 unicode character at a time? And does it use UTF-16 or UTF-32? For the answer to this question I [looked up the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference):

> `\u`nnnn - Matches a Unicode character by using hexadecimal representation (exactly four digits, as represented by nnnn).

So C# regex supports UTF-16 (2 bytes), but not UTF-32. A pattern like `.{1}` will catch exactly 1 UTF-16 character.

So then the solution was simply to not try and get 2 items out of `itemMatch.ToString().ToCharArray()` in the original question - because there is only 1 item there! Here is the missing solution for rule 3 (the part that I was stuck on):

```
        Regex itemRegex = new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9<>[\]:\.,_\s-]", RegexOptions.Compiled); // {1} is implied

        foreach (Match itemMatch in itemRegex.Matches(s))
        {
            char unicodeChar = itemMatch.ToString().ToCharArray()[0]; // 1 char = 16 bits
            int unicodeNumber = (int)unicodeChar;
            string unicodeHex = unicodeNumber.ToString("X4");
            s = s.Replace(itemMatch.ToString(), "<U+" + unicodeHex + ">");
        }
        return s;
```

Comment: You can remove first three lines of the loop body and just go with `$"<U+{(int)itemMatch.ToString()[0]:X4}>"` (Or `String.Format(...)` instead of `$` for older C#.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the loop, but just one line, `s = itemRegex.Replace(s, m => $"<U+{(int)m.Value[0]:X4}>");`

Comment: Also, if you use `RegexOptions.Compiled` then make sure `itemRegex` object is created only once and used every time. Otherwise you don't get better performance. Sorry for comment-spamming you.

Comment: @Dialecticus, I could, but then it would be less readable and harder to debug using breakpoints. I did it this way on purpose. Thanks for the tip about `RegexOptions.Compiled` tho.